# How to make object following player smooth

Tags: roblox

I use MoveTo for following the position and change the CFrame for rotation but it looks supper jaggy. I think the problem is that the code is on the server-side and not on the client-side since I want other players to be able to see the object following the player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using weldConstrain. You can create it by code and connect 2 parts to it. The parts are going to stay at the same relative position from each other. Here is a link for the API reference about the subject: https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/WeldConstraint
Here is an example code that adds a part at the top of a player's head when it joins the game:

```
local Players = game:GetService('Players') -- get's the players service

local function OnPlayerAdded(player)
  local PlayerCharacter = player.Character
  -- waits until the player's character loads
  while PlayerCharacter == nil do
      wait(1)
      PlayerCharacter = player.Character
  end

  -- Get's the player's model in workspace
  local PlayerModel = workspace:WaitForChild(PlayerCharacter.Name)
  -- Get's the player's head inside it's model
  local PlayerHead = PlayerModel:WaitForChild('Head')
  -- Write the path to the part you want to follow the player, bellow
  local FollowPartOriginal = workspace:WaitForChild('Part')
  -- If you want to clone the part, so more players can be followed by it,
  -- don't delete the line below, if you want only 1 part, delete the line below.
  local FollowPart = FollowPartOriginal:Clone()
  -- set's the part position on top of the player's head, with an offset
  FollowPart.Position = PlayerHead.CFrame.p + Vector3.new(0,2,0)
  FollowPart.Parent = workspace
  -- creates a weldconstrain
  local WeldConstraint = Instance.new('WeldConstraint')
  -- connect's the weld to the player's head and the other part 
  WeldConstraint.Part0 = PlayerHead
  WeldConstraint.Part1 = FollowPart
  WeldConstraint.Parent = PlayerHead
end

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(OnPlayerAdded)
```

Place this code in a script(not a local script).
If you use the function separately, don't forget to put the player parameter. The parameter needs to contain the player Instance(ex: game.Players.PlayerName)
To change the part position, use the offset in this line of the code:

```
FollowPart.Position = PlayerHead.CFrame.p + Vector3.new(write offset here)
```

If you want the part the stop following the player, make a script to delete the part, or the weld constrain(child of the player's head)

Comment: Did you find my answer useful?